# Expanded all WPF Treeview Items

Tags: wpf, treeview, c#-4.0

I'm trying to iterate through my Treeview, expanding all nodes however it runs into an InvalidCastException when ran;

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.

My Code;

```
foreach (TreeViewItem treeitem in thetreeView.Items)
{
   treeitem.IsExpanded = true;
}
```

Any ideas?  I want to fire this from a button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just add this style

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem"> 
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" /> 
    </Style> 
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

for code please go through this link may be this can help u

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=55

Comment: Though I'd like todo this at runtime, the initial state of the Treeview should be closed.  My idea is to have a collapse/expanded all button.

Comment: for that please read this article with example
http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=55

Comment: Agreed. Bea's postings covered the fundamentals of this.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that.  Confused me somewhat, tried to write something from scratch instead.

Answer (score 4):

I've found an "Hackish" solution for that.
It does not involved with inheritance like the solution suggested [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/491#.UgJTg5IwfGA) (by **Kishore Kumar**)

I've added two buttons - "Collapse all" and "Expand All".

Code Behind:

```
    private void btnCollapseAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in treeView.Items)
        {
            DependencyObject dObject = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            CollapseTreeviewItems(((TreeViewItem)dObject));
        }
    }

    private void btnExpandAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in treeView.Items)
        {
            DependencyObject dObject = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            ((TreeViewItem)dObject).ExpandSubtree();
        }
    }

    private void CollapseTreeviewItems(TreeViewItem Item)
    {
        Item.IsExpanded = false;

        foreach (var item in Item.Items)
        {
            DependencyObject dObject = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

            if (dObject != null)
            {
                ((TreeViewItem)dObject).IsExpanded = false;

                if (((TreeViewItem)dObject).HasItems)
                {
                    CollapseTreeviewItems(((TreeViewItem)dObject));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My solution is based on [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bf0895e-eee1-4171-82c2-5164e4786efa/treeview-collapseexpand-wpf-c-issue)

Answer (score 0):

[Bag of tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) has a demo called "TreeView Expand" that has a tree view with expand all and collapse all buttons (and some more)